# How to get table rate calculation?

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, table-rates

I need to calculate the shipping price based on the condition `Weight Vs Destination` in Magento 2. when I added a product of particular weight then I got preferable shipping price, But when I tried to add more no of the same product to the cart I found that the table rate is not changing based on the increased weight. So please suggest me how to add the weight values in the table rate CSV file. For now, I have used '*' in the weight( and above) column. The figure below shows the CSV file I imported to Magento 2 Table rate shipping method.

[image]

I am adding my results from the checkout page 
This is the expected result given below
[image]

The image below shows the result I am getting on my website. Here the table rate calculations are not increased as the weight is increased.
[image]

Comment: you need to add weight in column for example 2,4,6 etc.. and import it again.so it will take rate based on weight in CSV

Answer (score 0):

You can add weight in kgs in `weight` column.

For more information related to table Rated shipping method check here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Hope this help!